# Finding a group's ID by only knowing its alias

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's say I know the group I'm interested in has this URL: [`https://www.facebook.com/groups/framerjs/`](https://www.facebook.com/groups/framerjs/).

I've been looking for a way to map an URL like this (without any other source of information) to a specific group ID, using the Graph API, but there seems no way to do that.

I've experimented with the following:

- **Accessing `/me/groups`:**
  This endpoint gives out the groups I've subscribed to (within which the group I'm looking for is included), but there's no information in the response that lets me map `framerjs` to an ID, since the response will only contain the full (formatted) group name, such as `Framer JS`.
- **Using the group alias directly, e.g. `/framerjs/feed`:**
  This returns an error like `(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: framerjs`, supposedly because the API only allows using aliases for users and/or pages, and not groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search):

```
/search?q=framerjs&type=group
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Framer JS",
      "id": "385961098197634"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search?type=group&q=framerjs&icon_size=16&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_AewsQta1G58IkwuUNLJ8vZb35qrc0BS89MpO1ZiAVCRiwYjzWE_GkHRwxk6I1E5Sj2UprSuDxghIB4EJGEF8GxD7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this solution on multiple groups, though, and it seems a bit unreliable. While in the case of Framer JS it returns only one group (and the correct one), I found that in the case of some groups, searching for their alias will either result in an empty search or multiple entities being returned. In my case, I need to be 100% certain that I get the correct group for the search.

Comment: make sure you are using an access token for the search. try with different ones (app token, user token).

Comment: While searching, I was using a token with access to user_groups, but it still seemed unable to find the group. Maybe it's unrelated, but by searching for the group's url alias in Facebook's search bar, I also get no results.